# Minimal pairwise comparisons to combine multiple binary trees that are only relatively sorted?

Tags: algorithms, sorting, binary-trees

I'm intending on writing a program to let my friends make pairwise comparisons of computer generated images, ranking them. I'm mostly doing this for fun and to do some learning and I picked computer generated images because they are easy to come by. And also as I came a cross a thought experiment/problem I funny how goes do solve programmatically.

Because the number of images is likely to be far more than the number of people ranking them, I'm expecting to hit the [Condorcet Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_paradox) with cyclical preferences. I've also read a similar question with and [answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/134412/producing-a-total-or-partial-order-from-an-inconsistent-relation) that mentions it.

Essentially I was thinking of giving a point to an image if it was the one that was preferred. And then ranking based on total score. I have seen an [answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/135984/sorting-algorithm-for-ranking-hundreds-of-images-based-on-pairwise-comparison) on a similar question that mentions the Bradley-Terry-Luce model, but according to that the model doesn't handle nontransitivity.

Based on my earlier reading, it looks like the cyclic preferences due to the nontransitive nature of pairwise comparisons arise when multiple things being compared have equal scores, I've seen that described as a [Circle of Death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Circle_of_death) in round robin tournaments.

As a way of tiebreaking, I was planning on writing logic to switch to ranking subsections of the images that had 'tied' after a certain number of pairwise comparisons. That would be possible by letting users drag the subsections into an order.

The reason for not starting off this was, is that I didn't want to maybe give a list of 300 images they had to sort though in one go. Rather they can whittle away by pairwise comparisons first.

However, once each of my friends has ranked each subsection I need to join them together.

With the pre-ramble over, I need to find out how to combine these lists. I wondered if storing them as binary trees would help, as I could use the rankings within a subsection as values of each node.

But I don't think I can combine them with any common binary tree merging algorithm, as each individual tree is only relatively sorted.

But I do know if I can either look at past pairwise comparisons, or make a few more wisely chosen pairwise comparisons I check if the bottom ranked image of the first subsection (let's call it A) is preferred over the top of any other subsection (let's call it B) I can just insert B under A in the binary tree and rebalance it.

However I'm going to come across more occasions where the two subsections need to be more or less interleaved, which isn't possible without many many more pairwise comparisons.

In this, (probably irrelevant, unlikely and tenuously possible) thought experiment, how can I go about combining multiple binary trees, with minimal pairwise comparisons?